# On the Regularity of the Atomic Part of a Finite Measure on the Unit Interval

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $T$ be a countable subset of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}=\left[0,1\right)$, and enumerate $T$ as $\left\{t_{n}\right\} _{n\geq0}$, and let $\mathbf{a}:\mathbb{N}_{0}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be arbitrary, where $\mathbb{N}_{0}$ is the set of all non-negative integers. For any such $\mathbf{a}$, define a “measure” $\mu_{\mathbf{a}}$ on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ by the formal sum:$$d\mu_{\mathbf{a}}\left(x\right)\overset{\textrm{def}}{=}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathbf{a}\left(n\right)\delta_{t_{n}}\left(x\right)$$ where $\delta_{t_{n}}\left(x\right)$ is a point-mass/Dirac delta located at $t_{n}$. Note that if $\mathbf{a}\in\ell^{1}\left(\mathbb{N}_{0}\right)$ (i.e., $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left|\mathbf{a}\left(n\right)\right|<\infty$) then $d\mu_{\mathbf{a}}$ becomes a continuous linear functional on the space $C\left(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\right)$ of continuous complex functions on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, which then guarantees that $d\mu_{\mathbf{a}}$ is a bonafide finite complex Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.

On the other hand, suppose we only require $\mathbf{a}\in\ell^{2}\left(\mathbb{N}_{0}\right)$ (i.e., $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left|\mathbf{a}\left(n\right)\right|^{2}<\infty$). Then, clearly, $\mu_{\mathbf{a}}$ need no longer be a finite measure; for example, if $\mathbf{a}\left(n\right)=1/\left(n+1\right)$, then: $$\int_{0}^{1}d\mu_{\mathbf{a}}\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}=\infty$$ Nevertheless, I wonder: when $\mathbf{a}\in\ell^{2}\left(\mathbb{N}_{0}\right)$, can there exist a finite complex Borel measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ so that $\mu_{\mathbf{a}}$ is then the atomic part of $\mu$? More generally, if $\mu_{\mathbf{a}}$ fails to be a finite measure, is there a non-atomic measure we can add to it in order to create a finite measure?

Somewhat conversely, suppose we are given a finite complex Borel measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. Writing the atomic part of $\mu$ as $\mu_{\mathbf{a}}$ (using the notation defined above), must it then be that $\mathbf{a}\in\ell^{1}\left(\mathbb{N}_{0}\right)$? Or can it be in $\ell^{p}\left(\mathbb{N}_{0}\right)\backslash\ell^{1}\left(\mathbb{N}_{0}\right)$ for some $p\in\left(1,\infty\right]$?